# On any basic function I write in racket I get the following error

Tags: scheme, racket

On every even basic function I write on my Racket I am getting an error.

For example this is my function:

```
#lang racket
(define f   (lambda (x)
      (+ x 2)))
```

Here is my command line:

```
> (f 2)
```

Here is the error:

```
Type Checker: missing type for top-level identifier;
either undefined or missing a type annotation
identifier: f in: f
```

I will be extremely happy for help

Comment: Bottom left of the DrRacket window, make sure you choose "Determine language from source" or "Determine language from source custom".

Comment: Also, no `.` before `#lang racket`.

Comment: Did you click the run button before trying it in the interactions?

Comment: If you use DrRacket, the `.#lang racket` line should cause the interactions window to be completely disabled.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, if my memory is correct my problem was the one the usepla said.

Comment: and the reason why I wrote "." before # is because ine Stack overflow # alone makes that the test after it will be bold and the char '#' dissapears. If any one knows how to go around this issue in Stack Overflow I will be happy to hear :)

Comment: @Tomer Format your code as "code sample" (Ctrl-K).

Comment: Hi @uselpa I am reviewing my old questions for editting reasons. I thought that maybe you want to put your comment as an answer so that it might serve other newbies like myself?

Comment: @Tomer Your question doesn't reflect the initial problem anymore, the offending dot is gone. Just accept naomik's answer, I don't care about the points ;-)

Comment: Ahh thanks but the dot was not the problem, the problem was a starters mistake Determine language from source". The dot was just to write #lang (stack overflow didn't let me do that so I wrote it with a dot.)

Comment: @Tomer Ok then, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bottom left of the DrRacket window, make sure you choose "Determine language from source" or "Determine language from source custom".